# How to replace a mouse event call with custom method call in WPF Animation Styles

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, styles, onmouseover

I am working with a code that uses animation on rectangles arranged in a grid like table cells. The animation triggers on a mouseover event for now but needs to replaced by own custom method call instead. I need this because I working with touchless cursors (using the kinect) and basically I have my own method that detects if the cursor is currently on a particular cell/rectangle (much like the mouse-hover property). Here is the code for the animation style I am using as of now:

```
        Style PrepareAnimationStyle(String label)
        {
            Trigger animTrigger = new Trigger();
            animTrigger.Property = ContentElement.IsMouseOverProperty; //currently set on mouse hover. Will have to call explicitly for cursor.
            animTrigger.Value = true;

            System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation greenStroke = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF66CC00"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
            //greenStroke.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;
            System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation greenFill = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF66CC00"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
            //greenFill.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;
            System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation transparentFill = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation(Colors.Transparent, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation silverStroke = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation(Colors.Silver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard sbEnter = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard();
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(greenStroke, new PropertyPath("Stroke.Color"));
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(greenFill, new PropertyPath("Fill.Color"));
            sbEnter.Children.Add(greenStroke);
            sbEnter.Children.Add(greenFill);

            Storyboard sbExit = new Storyboard();
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(silverStroke, new PropertyPath("Stroke.Color"));
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(transparentFill, new PropertyPath("Fill.Color"));
            sbExit.Children.Add(silverStroke);
            sbExit.Children.Add(transparentFill);

            animTrigger.EnterActions.Add(new BeginStoryboard() { Storyboard = sbEnter });
            if (label != "chills")
                animTrigger.ExitActions.Add(new BeginStoryboard() { Storyboard = sbExit });

            Style cellStyle = new Style();
            cellStyle.Triggers.Add(animTrigger);

            return cellStyle;
        }
```

Can I replace this line? :

```
animTrigger.Property = ContentElement.IsMouseOverProperty;
```

Can this be done? If yes, how can I replace it with my own method call?

Or can I instead access the particular UI element and explicitly set the mouseover property to True? Something like the following:

```
     foreach (UIElement ui in grid.Children)
     {
                int index = grid.Children.IndexOf(ui);
                int rowIndex = index / numOfCols;
                int columnIndex = index % numOfCols;

                if (rowIndex == 0 && columnIndex == 5)
                    if (ui is System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle)
                         ui.SetValue(UIElement.IsMouseOverProperty, true);
     }
```

Will the second approach work? Do I have to then set the property to false as well?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011) for injecting such behavior

so define a class with the attached dependency property, and use it to set and unset the flag on your UI element

AnimationTrigger class

```
public class AnimationTrigger : DependencyObject
{
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsTriggered.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTriggeredProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsTriggered", typeof(bool), typeof(AnimationTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

changes in PrepareAnimationStyle method

```
animTrigger.Property = AnimationTrigger.IsTriggeredProperty;
```

finally to trigger the animation

```
ui.SetValue(AnimationTrigger.IsTriggeredProperty, true);
```

and to revert back animation

```
ui.SetValue(AnimationTrigger.IsTriggeredProperty, false);
```

---

`other answers`

secondly you may not be able to set the value of IsMouseOverProperty as it is a read-only property

also to complete the animation cycle you need to set the value to true followed by false